# Trac + AccountManagerPlugin: How do I get cookie sharing working?

Tags: authentication, cookies, trac, http-authentication

I have an active Trac installation with multiple projects. I am using the [AccountManagerPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin) to manage user accounts, and to allow users to manage their own accounts.

My current AccountManagerPlugin configuration looks like this:

```
[account-manager]
account_changes_notify_addresses = 
authentication_url = 
force_passwd_change = true
generated_password_length = 8
hash_method = HtDigestHashMethod
htdigest_realm = TracRealm
notify_actions = []
password_file = /home/sms/trac_sites/trac.htdigest
password_store = HtDigestStore
persistent_sessions = true
user_lock_max_time = 0
verify_email = false
```

This works great, except: **Each Trac project currently requires separate authentication.** The projects are unable to share their authentication cookies.

Setting `auth_cookie_path = /trac` does not work, because session data is stored in each project's own database; therefore one project cannot validate the cookie of another. Worse, this causes projects to overwrite each other's cookies.

Using an undocumented two-year-old monkey patch ([SharedCookieAuthPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SharedCookieAuthPlugin)) seems like a bad idea.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

SharedCookieAuthPlugin is indeed the way to go. The author of the plugin (k0s, alias Jeff Hammel) was the person who [requested](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/8486) the `auth_cookie_path` option, specifically for his plugin. The fact that it hasn't been updated in two years just means that it works as it is.

Comment: Actually, that just means that it's unmaintained.  There are open, unresolved issues open against it, and it looks like the current version was writtwn for Trac version 0.11.  Nevertheless, give it a try and see what happens.  You can always remove it if you run into problems.

Comment: Well, theres a single open issue, so this hardly allows concluding that it's unmaintained. Trac itself also has a few open issues, and I wouldn't call it unmaintained. But you're still right: http://trac-hacks.org/ticket/5566#comment:12

Comment: I didn't call it unmaintained because of the open issue, I called it unmaintained because the author said he wasn't maintaining it anymore :-)  The plugin is also tagged as "needsadoption", which usually signals that the previous maintainer has abandoned it.

Comment: I am sorry I've left this hanging so long; I simply haven't had time to try the proposed solution. I realize it's poor etiquette. I will get around to trying this.